# Export/Import Content Types/Contents to another Drupal site (version 6)

Tags: 7, nodes, importing-exporting, migrations

I'm looking for something to help me to export my content types / contents i have locally in a drupal project. i need to use it in another Drupal project.

I just stumbled upon the Bundle copy module but it is only available for Drupal 7 and my project is version 6.26 - I can't update my core unfortunately for various reasons.

is there something similar working for version 6 please? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For content types, views and much more you can use [features](http://drupal.org/project/features), while for the nodes, [node_export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

For content type -  Content Copy module  which lives in the CCK project for Drupal 6
   For node export - [Node export module](http://drupal.org/project/node_export)

Answer (score 0):

The [data_export_import](https://drupal.org/project/data_export_import) module is available for Drupal 6. If I am correct, this solution would be for content (data) not content types so you might want to still use features for the content types along with this module.

What I like about data_export_import is that it is an all-in-one module (for export AND import of data. Whereas as with other solutions, the import and export stages are done by separate modules, which *could* mean that extra work is needed ensuring compatibility of the export with the import.)